# How to calculate the residue of this function with this rectangle contour?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to evaluate the integral ${1 \over2 \pi i} \int f(‌\nu)\,d\nu $; where $f(‌\nu) = {\pi \cot(\pi \nu) \over z^2-\nu^2}$

This integral is on the rectangle contour from $(-N- {1\over2})\leq x \leq (N+ {1\over2})$, and $-N\leq y \leq N $

Comment: yeah that was a mistake. sorry! that should be a function of $\nu$

Comment: It cries out for the method of residues.  Can you identify the poles of $f(\nu)?$  Which are inside your rectangle?

Comment: There is a method shown in the book of Albowitz and Fokas. Example no 4.2.5
But i need help to understand that solution.